# How to pass dictionary as part of the payload in POST request in Advanced Rest Client

Tags: c#, json, rest, dictionary, rest-client

I am trying to use [Advanced Rest Client Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/related) for testing my WebApi locally
 and i would like to pass a dictionary as part of the payload to the POST request that i am trying to make. While debugging i found out that the dictionary even though i am passing it in json format doesn't deserialize correctly and count for  Dictionary remains zero.

Payload Example :

```
{
"DictionaryForEvaluationTelemetries" :{ "B":"{\"Counter\":\"500\"}"}
}
```

This is the simple code for the object which is part of the dictionary

```
[DataContract]
class Class1
{
        private int counter;

        [DataMember]
        public int Counter
        {
            get { return counter; }
        }

        public void Increment()
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
        }
}

[DataContract]
public class TelemetryPayload
{
        [DataMember]
        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Class1> DictionaryForEvaluationTelemetries { get; set; }
}

    [HttpPost]
    public void LogEvaluationTelemetry()
    {
// Internally the below method does :  JsonSerializer<T>.Deserialize(request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

                var telemetryPayload = Request.GetObjectFromBody<TelemetryPayload>();
    }
```

JSON Deserialization is done by System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;

public static class JsonSerializer<T> where T : class
{
        public static T Deserialize(string jsonObject)
        {
            byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonObject);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(array))
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(ms);
            }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON looks like a `Dictionary<string, string>` where the value string is a previously-serialized JSON string.  (Notice the escaping of the quotes in `"{\"Counter\":\"500\"}"`.)  Could your dictionary values have been double-serialized before posting them?

Comment: I am using the client and this serialization is not by code. I created this json manually and passed it as part of payload to rest client chrome extension

Comment: 1) Can you give an example of the JSON that is actually sent? 2) When you write `count remains zero` do you mean the dictionary has no entries, or `Class1.Counter` is zero?

Comment: Also, what serializer are you using on the server side to deserialize the JSON?  Is this WCF, Web API, ASP.NET, ... ?

Comment: I am using WebAPI. On the server side i use the  Request.GetObjectFromBody<TelemetryPayload>(); to deserialize the payload. DictionaryForEvaluationTelemetries .Count is zero. I expect it to be 1 since i have passed one key value pair as part of the payload. I have made some edits to the question. Let me know if you have more questions

Comment: What is type of serializer is `JsonSerializer<T>`?

Comment: Ok found the answer. The issue was in the way i was trying to deserialize. I changed the deserailzation method to use NewSoft.Json JsonConvert. var telemetryPayload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TelemetryPayload>(Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the json you are passing doesn't have an object that will map to Class1. Your json should look like this:

```
{
    "DictionaryForEvaluationTelemetries" : {"B": {"Counter": 500}}
}
```

where DictionaryForEvaluationTelemetries.B would map to Class1.

Or, depending on what the Request.GetObjectFromBody<> method does, probably more like this:

```
{"Counter" : 500}
```

Comment: @dbc Looks like a typo, do you mean a `set` method?

Comment: Yes, I meant to say, a `set` method is also needed for the value of `Counter` to be read successfully.  It could be private since the `DataMember` attribute has been applied.

Comment: Thanks for your help @dbc and Damien Jones. The JSON that you mentioned is the correct way of doing passing a dictionary. Another issue was there in my deserialization code

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems for the question asked above : 
1) Payload format was incorrect :

```
{
    "DictionaryForEvaluationTelemetries" : {"B": {"Counter": 500}}
}
```

2) For deserializing i was using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json. I changed it to use NewtonSoft.Json JsonConvert.DeserializeObject